# refresh_token only works once

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

I'm scratching my head over this.

Using a `JdbcTokenStore`:

I am able to login and get an `access_token` as well as a `refresh_token` from the `oauth/token` endpoint. The web client stores both tokens. After the `access_token` expires, and a HTTP 401 has been sent, the client attempts to get a new `access_token` by presenting the `refresh_token`.

The new `access_token` and `refresh_token` get stored again on the client side.

However, the second time this is done I am getting an `invalid_grant` error telling me the `refresh_token` would be wrong.

This is the log:

```
2018-12-17T20:24:42.193Z INFO [main.js:1033] Login success.

...

ngx-logger.js:250 2018-12-17T20:24:42.195Z INFO [main.js:1034] {
  "access_token": .72UGm5604uDyuY0eDSKE3s_Wr9GzhOFyYMsWoYKxdGs",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "refresh_token": .5tucDhuMJciUufeosI-FG1lO5WaWQCq9_7G7kDPGmMc",
  "expires_in": 4,
  "scope": "read write",
  "jti": "495c03d9-c19d-4239-9d94-9e96c49844f5"
}
ngx-logger.js:256 2018-12-17T20:24:42.198Z DEBUG [main.js:748] User is logged in.!


...

ngx-logger.js:250 2018-12-17T20:24:54.438Z INFO [main.js:843] Handling 401 error
ngx-logger.js:250 2018-12-17T20:24:54.441Z INFO [main.js:845] Refreshing access token
ngx-logger.js:250 2018-12-17T20:24:54.443Z INFO [main.js:1044] Attempting to refresh access token
ngx-logger.js:250 2018-12-17T20:24:54.446Z INFO [main.js:1045] refresh_token: .5tucDhuMJciUufeosI-FG1lO5WaWQCq9_7G7kDPGmMc

...

ngx-logger.js:250 2018-12-17T20:24:54.643Z INFO [main.js:854] Access token refreshed.
ngx-logger.js:250 2018-12-17T20:24:54.651Z INFO [main.js:855] {
  "access_token": .gets297iCBDdNNK2C29PBTxRP1VdM9ok3ilo1g5Ow0A",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "refresh_token": .NcJQOWDDo1q474LzvCeh37BjCn14I3E6e03JuWO208Y",
  "expires_in": 4,
  "scope": "read write",
  "jti": "0fa0c63e-2027-4780-9ce3-501608cdaee5"
}

... 

ngx-logger.js:247 2018-12-17T20:25:13.162Z ERROR [main.js:863] {
  "headers": {
    "normalizedNames": {},
    "lazyUpdate": null
  },
  "status": 400,
  "statusText": "OK",
  "url": "https://192.168.1.144:8443/oauth/token",
  "ok": false,
  "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
  "message": "Http failure response for https://192.168.1.144:8443/oauth/token: 400 OK",
  "error": {
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Invalid refresh token: .NcJQOWDDo1q474LzvCeh37BjCn14I3E6e03JuWO208Y"
  }
}
```

I have no idea what the problem might be here. Am I missing something?

Comment: It is similar like my problem. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53828014/spring-oauth2-api-oauth-token-is-unauthorized-after-tomcat-server-is-restar

Comment: @ZawThanoo Hi! Thanks for the hint but I think my problem is different. My token still works after restart. It just does not work after it gets refreshed a *second* time. Restarting the server is no issue for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had to set the `TokenEnhancerChain` to **not** reuse refresh tokens. It's obviously `true` per default because that's why we use `refresh_tokens` - they should behave just like `access_tokens` (If you're confused now: this was sarcasm - I have no idea *why* the default would be `true` and I'd be delighted if somebody could clarify this).

Anyway. In your configuration you want to set (something like):

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    TokenEnhancerChain enhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
    enhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Collections.singletonList(accessTokenConverter));
    endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore)
            .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter)
            .tokenEnhancer(enhancerChain)
            .reuseRefreshTokens(false)  // <-------------- Set to false
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}
```

> Related issue on github: [#867](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/867)