# spring + oauth2 /api/oauth/token is `Unauthorized` after Tomcat/server is restart

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I am using `spring-security-5`, `spring-boot 2.0.5` and `oauth2`. I have checked and test by online reference.

Like :

[Spring Security and OAuth2 to protect REST API endpoints](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-2-applications-and-oauth-2-legacy-appr)

[Spring Boot 2 Applications and OAuth 2](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-2-applications-and-oauth-2-legacy-appr)

Everything is fine in my project.

When I request this URL , `http://localhost:8080/api/oauth/token`, I get response as

[image]

**And I restart the server(Tomcat)**, I request that URL again, I get response as
[image]

So my question is, how the client-app can get `access_token` again after `Tomcat` or `spring-boot` application is **restart**?

**One thing**
For that kind of situation, if I delete the record of `OAUTH_CLIENT_DETAILS` table in database, It is OK to request again. I also get `access_token` again.

**Update**

Please don't miss understanding response `json` format, every response I wrap by custom object like as below.

```
{
    "status": "SUCCESS", <-- here my custom
    "data": {
        "timestamp": "2018-12-18T07:17:00.776+0000", <-- actual response from oauth2
        "status": 401,  <-- actual response from oauth2                 
        "error": "Unauthorized", <-- actual response from oauth2
        "message": "Unauthorized", <-- actual response from oauth2
        "path": "/api/oauth/token" <-- actual response from oauth2
    }
}
```

**Update 2**

I use `JDBCTokenStore`, all of `oauth` information keep in database

```
package com.mutu.spring.rest.oauth2;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore;

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    static final String CLIEN_ID = "zto-api-client";
//  static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "zto-api-client";
    static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "$2a$04$HvD/aIuuta3B5DjXXzL08OSIcYEoFsAYK9Ys4fKpMNHTODZm.mzsq";
    static final String GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD = "password";
    static final String AUTHORIZATION_CODE = "authorization_code";
    static final String REFRESH_TOKEN = "refresh_token";
    static final String IMPLICIT = "implicit";
    static final String SCOPE_READ = "read";
    static final String SCOPE_WRITE = "write";
    static final String TRUST = "trust";
    static final int ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 1*60;
    static final int FREFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 2*60;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                   .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {

        configurer
                .jdbc(dataSource)
                .withClient(CLIEN_ID)
                .secret("{bcrypt}" + CLIENT_SECRET)
                .authorizedGrantTypes(GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD, AUTHORIZATION_CODE, REFRESH_TOKEN, IMPLICIT )
//              .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                .scopes(SCOPE_READ, SCOPE_WRITE, TRUST)
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(FREFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `tokenStore` to something different than `InMemory`.

I tend to use redis,  as it scales very well, is fast as hell and once it's there you can use it as cache:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
class AuthorizationServerConfig : AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Bean
    fun tokenStore(): TokenStore = RedisTokenStore(redisConnectionFactory).apply {
        setAuthenticationKeyGenerator(authenticationKeyGenerator)
    }
}
```

Application.yaml:

```
spring:
    redis: 
        host: 0.0.0.0
        password:
        port: 6380
        database: 0
```

And to get if up and running with docker:

```
version: '3'
services:

  cache:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6380:6379"

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5454:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=mydb
```

The `JWTTokenStore` would enable you to go without 3rd party software and scales good as well, but makes it harder to revoke token.

For smaller applications, tokens may be ok to store in the database (see `JdbcTokenStore`).

Comment: I did not use `inMemory`. I already use `JdbcTokenStore` Could you check my update post?

Comment: Can u check what kind of `authenticationKeyGenerator` is used? I think the default one is using some runtime config. I remember having that as well and `@Autowired
    private lateinit var authenticationKeyGenerator: AuthenticationKeyGenerator` made it go away.

Answer (score 0):

In my question, even I use `JdbcTokenStore`, it is still getting `Unauthorized` response after restart the sever.

Now, I get a solution for my issue which is using `JwtTokenStore`. It is `stateless`. I just need to modify my `AuthorizationServerConfig` class as below. I don't need any `oauth` related table in my database now.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtTokenStore;

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    static final String CLIEN_ID = "zto-api-client";
//  static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "zto-api-client";
    static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "$2a$04$HvD/aIuuta3B5DjXXzL08OSIcYEoFsAYK9Ys4fKpMNHTODZm.mzsq";
    static final String GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD = "password";
    static final String AUTHORIZATION_CODE = "authorization_code";
    static final String REFRESH_TOKEN = "refresh_token";
    static final String IMPLICIT = "implicit";
    static final String SCOPE_READ = "read";
    static final String SCOPE_WRITE = "write";
    static final String TRUST = "trust";
    static final int ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 5*60;
    static final int FREFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 5*60;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    // replace
    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey("as-you-like-your-key");
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter()); // replace
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                   .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {

        configurer
                .inMemory() // replace
                .withClient(CLIEN_ID)
                .secret("{bcrypt}" + CLIENT_SECRET)
                .authorizedGrantTypes(GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD, AUTHORIZATION_CODE, REFRESH_TOKEN, IMPLICIT )
                .scopes(SCOPE_READ, SCOPE_WRITE, TRUST)
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(FREFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());// replace
    }
}
```